# Виджеты Tkinter в списках

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, tkinter

Хочу с помощью списка и индексов, правильно обращаться к виджетам.
Создал список `Tasks`, и после нажатия кнопки `ATB`, в `Tasks` добавляется виджеты.
Метод `add_task` :

```
def add_task(self):
        self.Tasks.append([Label(text = str(len(self.Tasks + 1)) + '.', background = 'black', foreground = 'white', font = 'Arial 25')])
        self.Tasks[len(self.Tasks)][0].place(x = 25, y = 225 + self.PlusY)
        self.PlusY += 100
        self.ATB.place(x = 25, y = 225 + self.PlusY)
```

ошибка : `TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "int") to list`.

пробовал изменить индексы, но не получилось.
если надо, код :

```
from tkinter import *

class BL():
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.Window = Tk()
        self.Window.title('BL')
        self.Window.attributes('-fullscreen', True)
        self.Window['background'] = 'black'
        self.PathForConfig = r'C:\Users\user\Documents\BAL\BL.cfg'
        self.PlusY = 0
        self.Tasks = []
        with open(self.PathForConfig) as self.Config:
            self.ConfigLines = self.Config.readlines()
            self.Level = int(self.ConfigLines[1])
            self.XP = int(self.ConfigLines[2])
            self.MaxXP = int(self.ConfigLines[3])
    def animation(self, func, obj, text, speed = 250, i = 0):
        if func == 0:
            if i < len(text):
                obj['text'] += text[i]
                self.Window.after(speed, lambda: self.animation(func, obj, text, speed, i = i + 1))
        if func == 1:
            if i < len(text):
                obj['text'] += text[i]
                obj['width'] -= 1
                self.Window.after(speed, lambda: self.animation(func, obj, text, speed, i = i + 1))
    def add_task(self):
        self.Tasks.append([Label(text = str(len(self.Tasks + 1)) + '.', background = 'black', foreground = 'white', font = 'Arial 25')])
        self.Tasks[len(self.Tasks)][0].place(x = 25, y = 225 + self.PlusY)
        self.PlusY += 100
        self.ATB.place(x = 25, y = 225 + self.PlusY)
    def run(self):
        self.Title = Label(text = '', background = 'black', foreground = 'yellow', font = 'Arial 25')
        self.Title.place(x = 25, y = 25)

        self.animation(0, self.Title, 'Добро пожаловать !', speed = 50)

        self.Progress = Label(text = '', background = 'black', foreground = 'white', font = 'Arial 25')
        self.Progress.place(x = 25, y = 125)

        self.animation(0, self.Progress, 'Ур. {} : {} / {}'.format(self.Level, self.XP, self.MaxXP), speed = 50)

        self.ATB = Button(text = '', command = self.add_task, background = 'white', font = 'Arial 25', foreground = 'black', border = 0, activebackground = 'black', activeforeground = 'white')
        self.ATB.place(x = 25, y = 225)

        self.animation(1, self.ATB, 'Добавить задачу', speed = 50)

        self.Window.mainloop()

BL().run()
```

можно ли хранить виджеты в списках?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка не из-за того, что вы в принципе пытаетесь виджеты в списке хранить, из-за этого куска кода:

```
len(self.Tasks + 1)
```

- тут вы к списку `self.Tasks` пытаетесь прибавить число. Для списков сложение - это конкатенация (добавление другого списка), отсюда получаете ошибку `TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "int") to list`.

Должно быть так:

```
len(self.Tasks) + 1
```

- т.е. к длине списка прибавить единицу, а не к самому списку.

Вообще, не нужно пытаться как можно больше упаковать в одну строку кода, вы так только себя путаете. Добавляемые элементы тоже не нужно оборачивать в списки (если, конечно, вы в эти списки не будете еще что-то добавлять).

Я бы записал так:

```
text = f"{len(self.Tasks) + 1}."
label = Label(text=text, background='black', foreground='white', font='Arial 25')
label.place(x = 25, y = 225 + self.PlusY)
self.Tasks.append(label)  # self.Tasks.append([label]) - если действительно нужно хранить списки
```

Comment: Про вашу запись это не так. Мне не переменные сохранять, а виджет.

Comment: чтобы обратится к нему

Comment: @АндрейКуликов, `self.Tasks.append(label)` добавляет в список не переменную, а ее значение (виджет). Потом через список и обращаетесь. От того что вы как можно больше кода упихнете в одну строку вместо того, чтобы использовать промежуточные переменные, суть не изменится - просто вы себя больше запутаете.